# UWP resource dictionary styles

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

Suppose I include the `Style` in `<ResourceDictionary>` in `<Application.Resources>` works fine. However, when I include the `Style` in `ResourceDictionary` and include it in `<Application.Resources>` doesn't work.

The style I tried to use has a target type `TimePickerFlyoutPresenter`, so I used it without `x:Key`.

Comment: Could you please share more information about the style that you mentioned and how you used it? It's confused about what you are doing just based on the post.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `MergedDictionaries` if you want to reference other `ResourceDictionary` from other files (which could contain styles, templates, converters, etc.).

Here is an example where I add several files that contain styles for different controls in App.xaml.

```xml
<Application x:Class="MyApp"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/Controls/Button.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/Controls/CheckBox.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/Controls/ComboBox.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/Controls/CommandBar.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/Controls/RadioButton.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/Controls/TextBlock.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/Controls/TextBox.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>

</Application>
```